# JS: capture a static snapshot of an object at a point in time with a method

Tags: javascript, object, methods, variable-assignment

I have a JS object I use to store DOM info for easy reference in an elaborate GUI.

It starts like this:

```
var dom = {
    m:{
        old:{},

        page:{x:0,y:0},
        view:{x:0,y:0},

        update:function(){
            this.old = this;
            this.page.x = $(window).width();
            this.page.y = $(window).height();
            this.view.x = $(document).width();
            this.view.y = window.innerHeight || $(window).height();
        }
```

I call the function on window resize:

```
$(window).resize(function(){dom.m.update()});
```

The problem is with dom.m.old. I would have thought that by calling it in the dom.m.update() method *before* the new values for the other properties are assigned, at any point in time dom.m.old would contain a snapshot of the dom.m object as of the last update – but instead, it's always identical to dom.m. I've just got a pointless recursion method.

Why isn't this working? How can I get a static snapshot of the object that won't update without being specifically told to?

Comments explaining how I shouldn't even want to be doing anything remotely like this in the first place are very welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

`this` is a reference to an object. You're not storing a copy of an object. You're storing a reference to that object. If you want a copy you'll need to copy the properties by hand. The easy way is to use [`$.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/):

```
this.old = $.extend({}, this);
```

Comment: On paper that looks right but in practice the use case functionality is the same – only now I have infinite recursion (dom.m == dom.m.old == dom.m.old.old etc)…

The $.extend() assignment there is the same as doing:

for(i in this) this.old[i] = this[i];

I can eliminate recursion by going:

for(i in this) if(typeof this[i] !== 'function' && i !== 'old') this.old[i] = this[i];

…taking on board what you're saying about *this*, I thought I could assign eval(this[i]) (which I thought would return the unbound contents as they stand), but surprisingly this doesn't help at all.

Answer (score 1):

OK right, the terminology is 'deep' copy. I would've thought it was the other way round (just get an impression rather than the object itself). So anyway Cletus is right but the syntax is:

```
this.old = $.extend(true,{},this)
```

And apparently 'snapshot' is 'clone' in developer lingo.